# How to use an external C function in assembly?

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, nasm, computer-science

I am creating code that calls a C function that gets the square root of an integer. The C function is external and in my folder. When calling it, i do not know how to give it a parameter so it knows what to calculate

I am using NASM Intel x86_64, Assembler is gcc, i do not know the current edition. I am using Linux

Currently my code is:

```
xor rsi, rsi       ;just clears rsi
mov rsi, r15       ;r15 held the value that is supposed to be the parameter
call square
```

It currently just prints out a 0 as it is not taking a correct value.

How do i get it to take in the parameter?

Thank you.

Comment: Different compiler could have different calling conventions (which includes different naming conventions). It's also very platform-dependent. So please [edit] your question to tell us what C compiler you're using, what version of it, and what platform (OS) you're working on.

Comment: The first six integer arguments (from the left) are passed in RDI, RSI, RDX, RCX, R8, and R9, in that order, all additional arguments are pushed onto the stack in reverse order.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the System V AMD64 ABI calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#System_V_AMD64_ABI) the first argument should be in the `rdi` register.

You need to copy the value to `rdi` instead of `rsi`.